# Проблемы с валидацией

Tags: java, spring

При добавлении invNum которого нету в базе все работает и добавляется, а вот если есть уже такой в базе то ошибка!
класс валидации

```
@Component("bookValidator")
public class BookValidator implements Validator {

@Autowired
private CatalogBooksService catalogBooksService;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return CatalogBooks.class.equals(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(@Nullable Object o, Errors errors) {
    CatalogBooks catalogBooks = (CatalogBooks) o;
    if (catalogBooksService.getCatalogBookByInvNum(catalogBooks.getInvNum()) != null){
        errors.rejectValue("invNum","jjj","Книга с таким инвентарным номером уже существует!");
    }
}
```

}

так получаю из базы существующий номер

```
 @Override
public CatalogBooks getCatalogBookByInvNum(int invNum) {
    CatalogBooks catalogBooks = (CatalogBooks) currentSession().createQuery("from CatalogBooks c where c.invNum =:inv")
            .setParameter("inv",invNum)
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .uniqueResult();
    return catalogBooks;
}
```

это контроллер

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/bookAdd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String bookNew(@ModelAttribute @Valid CatalogBooks catalogBooks,
                        @ModelAttribute Category category,
                      BindingResult bindingResult,
                      Model model){
     bookValidator.validate(catalogBooks, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        Map<String, String> errorsMap = ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);
        model.addAttribute("errorsMap", errorsMap);
        model.addAttribute("book", catalogBooks);
        model.addAttribute("category", categoryService.categoryList());
    }else {
        Category category1 = categoryService.getCategory(category.getId_Category());
        catalogBooks.setCategory(category1);
        catalogBooksService.addCatalogBook(catalogBooks);
        model.addAttribute("addOk", true);
    }
    model.addAttribute("category", categoryService.categoryList());

    return "/bookAdd";
}
```

Выскакивает ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

класс Category

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categoryes")
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "id_category")
private int id_Category;

@Column (name = "name")
private String categoryName;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
private Set<CatalogBooks> catalogBooks;

public Category() {
}

public int getId_Category() {
    return id_Category;
}

public void setId_Category(int id_Category) {
    this.id_Category = id_Category;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public Set<CatalogBooks> getCatalogBooks() {
    return catalogBooks;
}

public void setCatalogBooks(Set<CatalogBooks> catalogBooks) {
    this.catalogBooks = catalogBooks;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category{" +
            "id_Category=" + id_Category +
            ", categoryName='" + categoryName + '\'' +
            //", catalogBooks=" + catalogBooks +
            '}';
}
```

}

класс CatalogBooks

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "catalog_books")
public class CatalogBooks {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_catalog_book")
private int id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "catalogBooks")
Set<Give> gives;

@NotBlank(message = "Название книги не может быть пустым")
@Column (name = "name")
private String name;

@Column (name = "author")
private String author;

@Column (name = "year")
private int year;

@Column (name = "inv_num")
private int invNum;

@Column (name = "count_book")
private int countBook;

public CatalogBooks(){
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public int getInvNum() {
    return invNum;
}

public void setInvNum(int invNum) {
    this.invNum = invNum;
}

public int getCountBook() {
    return countBook;
}

public void setCountBook(int countBook) {
    this.countBook = countBook;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CatalogBooks{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", category=" + category +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", author='" + author + '\'' +
            ", year=" + year +
            ", invNum=" + invNum +
            ", countBook=" + countBook +
            '}';
}
```

}

Comment: классCategory скинь

Comment: даже не знаю почему обращается здесь в класс Category если я ищу в другом классе

Comment: скопируйте полностью классы Category  и CatalogBooks , ругается на некорректный геттер, который у вас в вопросе в виде "+ геторы и сеторы". кроме того, измените int на Integer. в таких случаях примитивы - плохое решение

Comment: если добавить в класс Category поле 
@Transient
    private int invNum; с гетором и сетором то все работает

Comment: странно почему в логах ругается на  пропертю класса Category, а скинутые классы показывают, что это пропертя в каталоге, можете скинуть классы до того как меняли?

Comment: Ничего не менял в классах, или что-то другое имеете ввиду? По наблюдению почему-то в валидаторе при записи ошибки поле invNum обращается почему-то к Category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ModelAttribute Category category, надо было ставить после BindingResult bindingResult,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bookAdd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String bookNew(@ModelAttribute @Valid CatalogBooks catalogBooks,
                      BindingResult bindingResult,
                      @ModelAttribute Category category,
                      Model model){
```